# Mono NetworkStream can't read data

Tags: c#, .net, mono, networkstream

I've got some C# code that works fine on Windows but I can't make it works on Mono Framework.

I'm using the last Mono 3.x branch. I know it's not stable but I'm curious what could happen and why a NetworkStream alway returns false on DataAvailable and I'm completely sure that there's a data  (tested at the same moment on Win).

So here's some code for reading from a NetworkStream:

```
public static class NetworkStreamHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronously reads a byte array from the NetworkStream object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The NetworkStream object to read.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The byte array size to read.</param>
    /// <param name="dataChunkSize">The data chunk size that used for reading chunks from the stream.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a task presents the asynchronious array read operation.</returns>
    public static async Task<Byte[]> ReadBytesAsync(this NetworkStream stream, Int32 count, Int32 dataChunkSize = 512)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("count should not be less 1");
        }
        if (dataChunkSize <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("dataChunkSize should not be less 1");
        }

        var dataChunk = new Byte[dataChunkSize];
        var destination = new List<Byte>(count);
        var currentBytesRead = 0;
        var remainedBytesToRead = count;
        var bytesToRead = 0;
        var done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            bytesToRead = remainedBytesToRead > dataChunk.Length ? dataChunk.Length : remainedBytesToRead;
            if (stream.DataAvailable) 
            {
                currentBytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync (dataChunk, 0, bytesToRead);
            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("delay");
                await Task.Delay(10);
                continue;
            }

            if (currentBytesRead == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            destination.AddRange(dataChunk.Take(currentBytesRead));
            remainedBytesToRead -= currentBytesRead;
            done = remainedBytesToRead == 0;
        }

        return destination.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I use this code when I get a NetworkStream object from a TcpClient object after successful connection.

Comment: Do you mean `DataAvailable` is *always* `false`, or just the first time through the loop? P.S. You don't need `DataAvailable` (or `Task.Delay`) here.

Comment: Yes. It's always false. If I read without checking DataAvailable I always got an AggregationException with an inner exception IOException: EndRead failure.

Comment: It works correct without any DataAvailable checks on Win.

Comment: Sounds like the `IOException` is the core problem. Any inner exception details?

Comment: Seems there's two exception in the stacktrace: Exception: EndRead failure and Exception: Connection reset by peer.

Comment: That's a TCP/IP error; I describe it near the end of [this post on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/error-handling.html). It's possible the Microsoft `WebClient` is ignoring it (if the reply has already completed) but the Mono `WebClient` is not.

Comment: I tried to suppress this exception but currentBytesRead is 0 after all and no data added to the buffer.

Comment: It still sounds like a network issue to me. Try using Fiddler on both tests and compare them.

Comment: I've got an RST signal every time I try to write to a network stream (a handshake request). Very strange behaviour. Should investigate how it works with other OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved long ago. A server broke connections from some ip address range.

Comment: Can you add some context? Is this a Mono bug? In what version?